# sort list a based on list b, but maintain original order of list a wherever b values are equal

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to sort list A based on list B(descending order) such that if two list A,B are

```
A=["k","a","l","d"]
B=[4,3,7,22]
```

after sorting, ( sort A based on desc(B) )
`A=["d","l","k","a"]`

However if `B=[0,0,0,0]`
I would like A to remain `A=["k","a","l","d"]` after sorting too

so wherever values are equal, the original order must be retained.
if `B=[0,22,5,0]` and `A=["k","a","l","d"]`
then, after sorting, `A=["a","l","k","d"]`

I have tried using `A= [x for _,x in sorted(zip(B,A),reverse=True)]`,

- with if `A=["k","a","l","d"]` and `B=[0,0,0,0]`, this gives
  `A=["a","d","k","l"]` but I want A to remain `A=["k","a","l","d"]`
- with if `A=["k","a","l","d"]` and
  `B=[0,22,5,0]`, this gives `A=["a","l","d","k"]` but I want A to be `A=["a","l","k","d"]`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
A = ["k", "a", "l", "d"]
Bs = [[4, 3, 7, 22], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 22, 5, 0]]

for B in Bs:
    res = [a for _, a in sorted(enumerate(A), key=lambda x: B[x[0]], reverse=True)]
    print(B, res)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 3, 7, 22] ['d', 'l', 'k', 'a']
[0, 0, 0, 0] ['k', 'a', 'l', 'd']
[0, 22, 5, 0] ['a', 'l', 'k', 'd']
```

As an alternative, you could use:

```
it_B = iter(B)
res = sorted(A, key=lambda _: next(it_B), reverse=True)
```

Both ideas work because [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (the underlying algorithm of `sorted`) is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). Since you are using just one key, when the values are equal, they conserve the appearance order.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict that maps `A` to `B`, and use the mapping as a key function to sort `A`:

```
order = dict(zip(A, B))
output = sorted(A, key=order.get, reverse=True)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/FailingCloseTruespace#main.py

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method I've found is to use numpy's Argsort.

```
index = np.argsort(B)
a = a[index]
```

Order is kept if they are all the same (i.e. `[0,0,0,0]`).